# Getting Google App Engine to respect the script's User Agent

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How may i get Google App Engine to respect the User Agent supplied to file_get_contents() in a PHP script?

Google App Engine ignores whatever user_agent I send to PHP file_get_contents(), instead sending:

> AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: s~pageslicer)

This is a particular problem because when getting a page from www.kickstarter.com, the result is this fail:

[image]

Running the script outside GAE, using the GAE user_agent causes:

> HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests

whereas user_agent

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox 30.0

succeeds, so I'm hoping the GAE user_agent is the cause of the fail from GAE.

Comment: This is ( probably) a security measure so people can complain about your aggressive app, if needed. It's unlikely you can do anything about this as you are using a GAE provided library.